# JSON to match key/values and get the total values for each key

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, mapreduce

I need help displaying a total of sessionTime to every goalName from an api I have created. I have tried mapping and reducing but was only able to get the total sessionTime.

I expect the results to come like this:

Learn Italian : 6

Parla con il mio amico in Italiano : 1

```
"records": [
    {
      "sessionTime": 1,
      "goalName": "Learn Italian",
      "timeStapmed": "10:08:23",
      "date": "11/08/2021",
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "sessionTime": 5,
      "goalName": "Learn Italian",
      "id": "PFKFKZ",
      "timeStapmed": "10:14:48",
      "date": "11/08/2021"
    },
    {
      "sessionTime": 1,
      "goalName": "Parla con il mio amico in italiano",
      "id": "aP_g1-",
      "timeStapmed": "10:21:28",
      "date": "11/08/2021"
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for an [`array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) loop,

```js
records.reduce(
  (acc, { sessionTime, goalName }) =>
    acc?.[goalName]
      ? { ...acc, [goalName]: acc[goalName] + sessionTime }
      : { ...acc, [goalName]: sessionTime },
  {}
);
```

we can go though each object and keep a sum of their values in the `acc` variable.

**Full code:**

```js
let records = [
  {
    sessionTime: 1,
    goalName: "Learn Italian",
    timeStapmed: "10:08:23",
    date: "11/08/2021",
    id: 1,
  },
  {
    sessionTime: 5,
    goalName: "Learn Italian",
    id: "PFKFKZ",
    timeStapmed: "10:14:48",
    date: "11/08/2021",
  },
  {
    sessionTime: 1,
    goalName: "Parla con il mio amico in italiano",
    id: "aP_g1-",
    timeStapmed: "10:21:28",
    date: "11/08/2021",
  },
];


let newRecords = records.reduce((acc, {sessionTime, goalName}) => acc?.[goalName] ? {...acc, [goalName]: acc[goalName] + sessionTime} : {...acc, [goalName]: sessionTime}, {})

console.log(newRecords)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try first to `filter` the elements you wanna calculate their sum.

```
const learnItalianTotal = records.filter(elm => elm.goalName === "Learn Italian")
.reduce((acc, cur) => acc.sessionTime + cur.sessionTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const records = [
    {
        sessionTime: 1,
        goalName: 'Learn Italian',
        timeStapmed: '10:08:23',
        date: '11/08/2021',
        id: 1
    },
    {
        sessionTime: 5,
        goalName: 'Learn Italian',
        id: 'PFKFKZ',
        timeStapmed: '10:14:48',
        date: '11/08/2021'
    },
    {
        sessionTime: 1,
        goalName: 'Parla con il mio amico in italiano',
        id: 'aP_g1-',
        timeStapmed: '10:21:28',
        date: '11/08/2021'
    }
];


var result = records.reduce( ( accumulator, { sessionTime, goalName} ) => {
    accumulator[goalName] = accumulator[ goalName ] ? (accumulator[goalName] + sessionTime): sessionTime;
    return accumulator;
}, {} );

console.log(result);
```

Output

```
{
    "Learn Italian": 6,
    "Parla con il mio amico in italiano": 1
}
```